# why is something inserting ko.js as a script tag?

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, single-page-application, durandal

This looks like ko.js is getting dynamically constructed by a javascript library.  I can't find a reference for it in my project.  Where is this reference comming from?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="ko" src="App/ko.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without know what code you are using, I'll take some guess:

If you are using the Code Camper SPA sample or Hot Towel or any Durandal solution, then look in the BundleConfig.cs file. It contains a reference to all css and js that the sample uses, including knockout.js

If you are using something else, then the knockout.js file is likely being optimized somewhere. search the solution for the term "knockout" and you will find any files that refer to it.

However, if you are using Durandal, then it depends on Knockout.

Comment: found this (function (root) {
define('ko', function () { return root.ko; }); in main.js.  Looks like  an alias, but not sure what convention lets root.ko act like this.

Comment: that code is part of require.js. if ko sees that require.js is going to load it using AMD, then ko wont put itself in the global namespace. But then knockout plugins wont be able to find it easily (unless you shm all of the properly too). so that code lets AMD load ko and then puts the ko variable back in the global root namespace.

Comment: that makes sense.  Can AMD analyze the anon function?  Where are the by convention dependencies defined?  ty.  btw: found this, http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim, but couldn't find a reference to it in any example code that I have.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but are you looking for [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) ?

> RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader.

Comment: require is wired in already.  Just trying where ko.js is coming from.  ko is not a file that I want.